# How to use Hive TABLESAMPLE with subquery

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I'm using **Hive version 1.1.0**.

I'm trying to get a sample from a table using `TABLESAMPLE` statement with subquery to use `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * FROM table WHERE field='A') f
TABLESAMPLE(1 PERCENT);
```

But I have an error:

```
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:45 missing EOF at 'TABLESAMPLE' near 'f' (state=42000,code=40000)
```

How to correctly use `TABLESAMPLE` with subqueries?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about hive 1.x. But in hive 2.1, `TABLESAMPLE` can be used right after the table name.
So, you need to add tablesample after table and then put where in outer clause. This is working in my hive. Not sure about your version.
Logically it makes sense, we should pick a sample and then work on it.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * FROM mytable TABLESAMPLE(1 PERCENT)) f
WHERE field='A'
```

Of course if you want to know more you can refer to hive guide.
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Sampling